# Python: try except else Strange behavior

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

When I execute the following code, I am getting an exception instead of normal behavior.

```
try:
    fun1(1)
    fun1(1)
except Exception as e:
    print "exception"
else:
    print "hi"


def fun1(i):
    if i == 0:
        raise Exception()
    else:
        print "no exception"
```

The above code doesn't have any exceptions, so instead of printing "no exception" it shows "exception" as output.

Comment: You get a `NameError`...

Answer (score 2):

You *do* have an exception; you are catching the `NameError` exception (which is a subclass of `Exception`). You get that exception because `fun1` *doesn't exist yet*.

Move the `fun1()` definition to *before* the `try..except` or move that code into a function you call *after* `fun1()` has been created.

You'd also be better off with using a less-generic exception, it'd would have made the problem apparent much earlier; you could use `ValueError` if you want to test things, it is far less likely to be thrown for unrelated issues:

```
>>> try:
...     fun1(1)
...     fun1(1)
... except ValueError:
...     print "exception"
... else:
...     print "hi"
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'fun1' is not defined
>>> def fun1(i):
...     if i == 0:
...         raise ValueError()
...     else:
...         print "no exception"
...
>>> try:
...     fun1(1)
...     fun1(1)
... except ValueError:
...     print "exception"
... else:
...     print "hi"
...
no exception
no exception
hi
>>> try:
...     fun1(0)
... except ValueError:
...     print "exception"
... else:
...     print "hi"
...
exception
```